# Copy files in Unix generated in 24 hours

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am trying to copy files which are generated in the past one day (24 hrs). I am told to use `awk` command but I couldn't find the exact command for doing this. My task is to copy files from `/source/path` --> `/destination/path`.

```
 find /source/path -type f -mmin -60 -exec ls -al {} \;
```

I have used the above command to find the list of files generated in the past 60 mins, but my requirement is to copy the files, and not just knowing the file names.

Comment: Looks fine, just go ahead and use the file names you computed with the `xargs` utility or use the `cp` command in the `exec` option instead of the `ls -l` you now do.

Comment: Why do you ask? If you care about source files, you should use some [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) (perhaps thru http://github.com/ ....)

Answer (score 1):

Just go ahead an exec `cp` instead of `ls`:

```
find /source/path -type f -mmin -60 -exec cp {} /destination/path \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really close! Take the name of files and use it for copy.

```
 find /source/path -type f -mmin -60 -exec ls -al {} \; |\
 while read file
 do
   cp -a "${file}" "/destination/path"
 done
```